# smooth scrolling images with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate, slider

I am making a logo slider using jQuery. My first idea is to use a large single image composed of all logos placed as background and animate its position. The idea behind this was to reduce http request by loading only a single file.

The jQuery code is something like this:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    var current = 0;
    function bgscroll(){
      // 20 pixel row at a time
      current -= 20;
      // move the background with backgrond-position css properties
      $('#slider').animate({'background-position' : current+'px'}, 100, 'linear');}
      setInterval(bgscroll, 1);
    });
</script>
```

However there is a problem with animation. It flickers and its not smooth.
So anyone have any ideas how I can make this animation smoother?

Current CSS

```
#slider{
  height: 97px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("../img/logos-long.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: added CSS. The animation doesnt end.

Answer (score 2):

In your example the `interval` is triggered more times before one `animation` cycle finishes, so...

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/emoruz/2)*

**NO need for `setInterval`**
when we can create a loop using your function and the animation callback!

```
$(function(){
  function bgscroll(){
    $('#slider').stop().animate({'background-position':'-=1000'},10000,'linear',bgscroll);
  }
  bgscroll(); // initiate!!
});
```

Clearing the animation queue using `.stop()` will make it (not perfect but) much, much better.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your timeout is executing faster than it takes each animation cycle to finish. If you increase the timeout delay to 100ms I would think the flickering will stop.